# Having trouble using js_link to add dropdown selector in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to implement widgets into my Bokeh diagrams. The first I would like is a drop down menu allowing the selection of other option strategies. I can't seem to figure out the js_link function in order to have the selection make a change on the graph. I fear I may have set up the diagram wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Div, Select, Slider, TextInput,CustomJSTransform
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.transform import transform
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot, column
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


strike1 = 20 #Long Call
strike2 = 33 #Short Call
strike3 = 30 #Long Put
strike4 = 60 #Short Put
premium1 = 0.5
premium2 = 1.6
premium3 = 2.1
premium4 = 1.5
price = np.arange(15,25,0.01)
contracts = 1
symbol = 'TSLA'
option = ['Long Call', 'Long Put', 'Short Call', 'Short Put', 'Bull Call Spread', 'Bear Put Spread', 'Straddle',
          'Butterfly Spread', 'Box Spread', 'Iron Condor']


def long_call(price, strike1, premium1, contracts):
    P = []
    for i in price:
        P.append((max(i - strike1, 0) - premium1) * (contracts * 100))
    return np.array(P)

def long_put(price, strike1, premium1, contracts):
    P = []
    for i in price:
        P.append((max(strike1 - i, 0) - premium1) * (contracts * 100))
    return np.array(P)

def straddle(price, strike1, premium1, premium2, contracts):
    P1 = long_call(price, strike1, premium1, contracts)
    P2 = long_put(price, strike1, premium2, contracts)
    return np.array(P1+P2)

def bull_call_spread(price, strike1, strike2, premium1, premium2, contracts):
    P1 = long_call(price, strike1, premium1, contracts)
    P2 = short_call(price,strike2, premium2, contracts)
    return np.array(P1+P2)

# Graph Items
x= price
y= long_call(price, strike1, premium1, contracts)
ds = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=price,
                           y=straddle(price, strike1, premium1, premium2, contracts)))

strategy = Select(title="Strategy", value="option", options=option)
strike = TextInput(title="Strike")


# create a new plot with a title and axis labels
p = figure(title="Option Payoff", x_axis_label='Underlying Price ($)', y_axis_label='Profit/Loss ($)')

# add a line renderer with legend and line thickness
p.line('x', 'y', source=ds, line_width=2)
p.varea(x='x', y1=transform('y', CustomJSTransform(v_func="return xs.map(x => x > 0 ? x : 0)")),
        y2=0, source=ds, color='#3cb371', fill_alpha=0.5)
p.varea(x='x', y1=transform('y', CustomJSTransform(v_func="return xs.map(x => x < 0 ? x : 0)")),
        y2=0, source=ds, color='#ff6347', fill_alpha=0.5)

select = Select(title="Strategy", value="Long Call", options=option)
select.js_link('options', p, 'y')

# initial load of the data

show(column(p,select,strike_input))
```

Answer (score 0):

All `js_link` does is to set the attribute of the second model to the value of the attribute of the first model whenever it changes. That's it.

`select.js_link('options', p, 'y')` basically says "Execute `p.y = select.options` whenever `select.options` is changed". `p` is an instance of `Figure` and it doesn't have the `y` property.

From your question and your code, it's unclear what you want. But you probably want to watch the `select.value` property for changes instead of `select.options`. And it seems that you need to change the data itself, meaning that you will have to either use `CustomJS` and rewrite all data manipulation functions in JS or use `bokeh serve` to be able to run the Python code in response to `select.value` changes. Or maybe you could precompute all of the required data so you don't have to run Python code in response to user actions, but you still have to write some code for `CustomJS`.